Is there any way to Trigger a Screenshot (not Save Screen) on iOS simulator using Appium?
To be clear, I am not trying to Save Screen

Cmd+S
little Camera icon in the simulator window's title bar
Simulator menu bar -> File -> Save Screen

I am trying to simulate a screenshot

Simulator menu bar -> Device -> Trigger Screenshot

Why?  Because the app I'm automating with Appium takes action when a user takes a screenshot.  Save Screen != Trigger Screenshot
There is no hotkey for this, so using Java Robot is out, perhaps there's another way?
